# In jest, how do I use "toHaveBeenCalledWith" and only match part of an object in an array argument?

Tags: jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I'm using Typescript and Jest.  In Jest, if I want to check if my function was called I can run

```
expect(myMockFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(arrayArgument);
```

I want to check if my function was called with an array argument that contains an object with some values.  For example,

```
expect(myMockFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith( [{x: 2, y: 3}] );
```

The actual call is made with a parameter that looks like

```
[{x: 2, y: 3, id: 'some-guid'}]
```

so my expect is failing because I don't have the id attribute in the first object of the array, but I would like to match and ignore the ID, since it will be different each time, even though the other arguments are the same.  How do I construct such an expect call with Jest?

Comment: Could you provide us your full test case?

Comment: Do you know in advance the number of elements in the array? Do you also know the properties of each object?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use a combination of `arrayContaining` and `objectContaining` to make this work.

Reference:

1. https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectarraycontainingarray
2. https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject

Here is some sample code for you:

```js
function something(a, b, somefn) {
    somefn([{
        x: a,
        y: b,
        id: 'some-guid'
    }]);
}

test('Testing something', () => {
    const mockSomeFn = jest.fn();
    something(2, 3, mockSomeFn);
    expect(mockSomeFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        expect.arrayContaining([
            expect.objectContaining({
                x: 2,
                y: 3
            })
        ])
    );
});
```

Sample output:

```
$ jest
 PASS  ./something.test.js
  ✓ Testing something (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.257 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
✨  Done in 0.84s.
```

Here is some explanation:

1. `toHaveBeenCalledWith` is called with `expect.arrayContaining` which verifies if it was called with an array
2. `expect.arrayContaining` has an array. The array has an object with `objectContaining` which does the partial match against the object.

Comment: I liked your answer. Does it work with if mock function is called with an array of objects?  (array with multiple object items)

Comment: It should work @SubratoPatnaik as this is a `arrayContaining`. It is testing if the array has an at least one object with partial match to two key value pairs as specified. If we want to match more elements, we can add that. There are many combinations possible.

Comment: Could you give one example about explaining this in your answer? It would be helpful.

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik, sorry I am confused. Which one are you talking about? An example of?

Comment: toHaveBeenCalledWith getting error need any import or npm for this? i am new to junit testing, can any one suggest please